# How to marge two rows and make single row in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to marge two rows and making single column. same data of row has to marge, and different data has to append to same row,

**example**:
 I got result from joining three tables like this

```
uid     name    diseaseid     intensity
1       xxxx    1              high
1       xxxx    2              low
```

Now I need final result like this

```
uid    name      diseaseid1   intensity       diseaseid2        intensity
1      xxxx       1             high           2                  low
```

Is there any option to make like this in Sql please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is actually something very simple, perhaps you you can do a google search and look up the word `UNION` for example


Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([uid] int, [name] varchar(4), [diseaseid] int, [intensity] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([uid], [name], [diseaseid], [intensity])
VALUES
    (1, 'xxxx', 1, 'high'),
    (1, 'xxxx', 2, 'low')
;

SELECT MAX([uid]) AS [uid]
       ,MAX([name]) AS [name]
       ,MAX([diseaseid1]) AS [diseaseid1]
       ,MAX([intensity1]) AS [intensity1]
       ,MAX([diseaseid2]) AS [diseaseid2]
       ,MAX([intensity2]) [intensity2]
FROM 
(
    SELECT [uid], [name]
    , CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN NULL ELSE [diseaseid] END AS [diseaseid1]
    , CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN NULL ELSE [intensity] END AS [intensity1]
    , CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN NULL ELSE [diseaseid] END AS [diseaseid2]
    , CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN NULL ELSE [intensity] END AS [intensity2]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [uid], [name], [diseaseid], [intensity], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [uid] ORDER BY Name) AS rn
        FROM #Table1
    ) T
) T
GROUP BY [uid], [name]

DROP TABLE #Table1
```

**EIDT**

Try this for **dynamic columns**

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([uid] int, [name] varchar(10), [diseaseid] int, [intensity] varchar(10))


INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([uid], [name], [diseaseid], [intensity])
VALUES
    (1, 'xxxx', 1, 'high'),
    (1, 'xxxx', 2, 'low'),
    (1, 'xxxx', 3, 'medium')


DECLARE @MaxRows INT
DECLARE @CurrentRow INT
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @CurrentRow = 1

SELECT @MaxRows = MAX(cnt) FROM (
SELECT COUNT(name) cnt FROM #Table1 GROUP BY [uid]
) AS T


SET @Query = '
SELECT  MAX([uid]) AS [uid]
       ,MAX([name]) AS [name]'

WHILE @CurrentRow <= @MaxRows
BEGIN
     SET @Query= @Query +  '
                ,MAX(diseaseid'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@CurrentRow)+') AS diseaseid'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@CurrentRow)+''
     SET @Query= @Query +  '
                ,MAX(intensity'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@CurrentRow)+') AS intensity'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@CurrentRow)+''
    SET @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1

END

SET @Query= @Query + ' FROM 
  (
    SELECT [uid], [name]'

SET @CurrentRow = 1

WHILE @CurrentRow <= @MaxRows
BEGIN
     SET @Query= @Query +  '
                , CASE WHEN rn='+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@CurrentRow)+' THEN [diseaseid] ELSE NULL END AS diseaseid'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@CurrentRow)+''
     SET @Query= @Query +  '
                , CASE WHEN rn='+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@CurrentRow)+' THEN [intensity] ELSE  NULL END AS intensity'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@CurrentRow)+''

     SET @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1
END

SET @Query= @Query + ' FROM 
    (
        SELECT [uid], [name], [diseaseid], [intensity], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [uid] ORDER BY Name) AS rn
        FROM #Table1
    ) T2
) T3
GROUP BY [uid], [name]'

PRINT (@Query)

EXEC (@Query)

DROP TABLE #Table1
```

Comment: thank you very much its working. but i need some more help. instead of creating tempovary table is any option from pivot or else. because i am getting result set which i got by joining three table. so i need to marge those result-set and i need to get final single row

Comment: hi please help me.. how can i take rn as dynamic. i cant specify as 2 or 1 as static... how can i achieve this

Comment: @SheelaKR rn column values 1 and 2 are used to combine 2 rows to single row. Provide additional data and output you needed so that i can modify query accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for response.But it is not coming properly. if i inserted two more rows It is displaying all the DiseaseID are same.

Comment: @SheelaKR check the latest updated the answer for  'dynamic columns' Try executing the updated answer you will get correct output

Comment: i used what you give the first solution. but if the disease is not present then it should come null. but in this case data is repeating same..

Comment: @SheelaKR i am glad you got solution consider accepting answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this one

```
select *,(select col1,col2 from table2 where uid=t.uid) from table1 t
```

Comment: Thanks for response. i tried this. but i am getting error like this. **Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.**

Comment: Did you use the select query in paranthesis after "where"? like select * from where (select...)

Answer (score 0):

i think u're doing your joins wrong...
It looks like u're doing a Union of u're only grouping by UID, name.
Without knowing the join, the best advice i can give u is to try experiment with Right and Left outer join.

I think this should do what u want.

Try joining the table u get from the diseaseid twice, once with join and the second time with right outer join, this way u should get the diseaseid2 without problems.